# Angular's Ng-Submit not executing command in firefox

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, firefox

I am able to submit this form in chrome, but not firefox. I read that firefox needs an actual submit button, but I do already have one so I don't understand this error.

```
<form class="form-addCards form-inline" role="form" ng-submit = "submit()">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="submitBtn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ng is angular. When I click the submit button I do get a message if I have not filled in the required fields. However, when I fill in the required fields and hit submit, the ng-submit function is never called. The button does flash like it is being clicked.

Comment: What does the `ng-` prefix refer to?  Angular? You have not provided enough context or background information.  What do you mean by "not working"?  Nothing happens? Does the button react to the mouse click?  We need lots more details or the question is likely to get closed.

Comment: I updated my post to be more clear.

Comment: It turns out that I had `prevent default` in my submit function and Firefox did not like this for some reason.

Comment: When the question is reopened you should answer it yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change button type from button to submit so `<button type="submit"> my button </button>`

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Doesn't my original code already use `type="submit"` on line 6?

Comment: You have an ng-form within a form which has button type button. What is the purpose of the ng-form?

Answer (score 1):

In my js I had `event.preventDefault();` in my submit function.  This was preventing firefox from executing the submit command.